# Is it a reasonable trade-off to use `sleep` in an asynchronous job?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, jobs, worker, distributed-system

Assume I have a scenario where I am processing a background job in a worker. It simply receives a URL for a file (image, video, pdf, ..) hosted on a remote CDN and the worker does its work as:

1. Some processing on the file content in-memory
2. Then calls a 3rd party API to retrieve [a signed valid URL](https://apiok.ru/en/dev/graph_api/methods/graph.user/graph.user.fileUploadUrl/get) for uploading the content to that same 3rd party.
3. Uploads the content to the 3rd party API – the response contains a unique file ID
4. [Sends a message to a user](https://apiok.ru/en/dev/graph_api/methods/graph.user/graph.user.messages/post) through the 3rd party API with the unique file ID received earlier

Now, the problem is between step (3) and (4). The constraint here is that the 3rd party API needs few seconds to process the file (step 3) before we actually send a message containing the file ID we just uploaded (step 4).

One more assumption here is that I need to make sure all 4 steps execute in one go, as in, not to have any partial failure opportunities.

### Possible approaches

- The most naive way to go is by using `sleep 5` between step (3) and (4), it might hurt / hard fail since I am not exactly sure how many seconds does the 3rd party API needs for processing, but according to my trials, 5 seconds sleep seemed alright.
- I could do an in-process exponential retry for 3 (or X) times for step (3), catch an exception from the 3rd party and attempt to do step (4) when step (3) is successful – this is what I have now, it works alright.
- I could perhaps either use a job scheduler or a ruby concurrency library to do step (4) in a delayed fashion. I don't appreciate this path as it feels like it is favouring complexity.

This piece of logic is built in Ruby, though the question might not be very Ruby specific and can be applicable in other languages, I would like to hear what Ruby folks think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API docs](https://apiok.ru/en/dev/graph_api/methods/graph.user/graph.user.fileUploadUrl/get) you linked to say:

> Attention! Some time needed by a server to process an uploaded file.
>   File should be sent to a chat after a short timeout (a couple of
>   seconds)

I would usually advise against something of this nature, but since your vendor specifically says "timeout", `sleep` is the best option.

Comment: Yes, their docs statement is something I referred to in my question. You are correct that I am operating under this assumption. Though I am still unsure that sleep is the best option, for the con I pointed to in my question above. It might hard fail since I am not exactly sure how many seconds does the 3rd party API needs for processing, but according to my trials, 5 seconds sleep seemed alright. It has the potential to fail more often than the exponential backoff technique that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try doing delayed task, as it will allow thread to continue working (so thread pool won't need to create new threads (they are quite expensive from memory side), your thread may continue doing useful job without need of context switch (which is expensive from CPU usage side), ...).

As for purity of solution, asynchronous programming should not involve any blocking tasks (we are actually fighting against blocking using asynchronous programming), so this is one more reason to use delayed task.

If application does not involve achieving highest performance (does Ruby performance oriented language?), so sleep may really be easiest, but not most optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks! > "asynchronous programming should not involve any blocking tasks."

I find it hard to agree with this statement. It is a job that runs within a worker. The job invocation nature is indeed asynchronous, but the work that encompasses can be and will be naturally blocking at some point. Perhaps I misunderstood or mis-explained something in my question.